# Running idle, with root privileges, while using TightVNC Server

Tags: python

I am trying to run idle with root privileges so as to use the RPi.GPIO module.

The RPi 2 is headless and I am using TightVNC Server. I get the error

```
Client is not authorized to connect to ServerTraceback
```

From googling I have discovered that this is a conflict with VNC but I have not been able to find a solution.

Strangely I somehow managed to resolve this problem when using the old Model B but I stupidly did not make a note of how.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Been there. :) I remember adding something to `~/.bashrc`. Not sure though. :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Run the vncserver as root
>
> `sudo vncserver`
>
> connect to the root vnc session then run
>
> `sudo DISPLAY=:2 idle` # with the right number for root's VNC.

Source: [trouble running idle as a root using vnc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=64083)

If that doesn't work, then something is up with XAUTHORITY.

Try adding

```
xhost +local:root
```

to `.bashrc` as [dastaan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/14032/dastaan) [suggests](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33482/running-idle-with-root-privilages-while-using-tightvncserver#comment-43595).

---

Just seen this:

> In fact no need for that, changing `sudo /usr/bin/idle` to `gksu /usr/bin/idle`
> is all is needed to make this work.

Source: [vnc-problem with idle running as sudo on raspberry pi](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/vnc-problem-with-idle-running-as-sudo-on-raspberry-pi.967333/)

Comment: Thank you greenonline gksu /usr/bin/idle does it. For those who see this you can find the file to change by Menu>programing>Python(2/3) and then right click

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Follow these steps.

1. Open `.bashrc` by `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Paste following code at the end.

   ```
   if [ -z "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
       if [ -e $HOME/.Xauthority ]; then
           export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority;
        fi;
   fi
   ```
3. Reboot by `sudo reboot` to make it effective.

It should work. :)

Hope it helps.